# onClick does not work where addEventListener does

Tags: javascript, html, codepen

This is the codepen link:
https://codepen.io/tanvircr7/pen/zYJgEZz

the HTML code

```
<h1>the HTML</h1>
<button id="btn-1">ClickME</button>
```

the Javascript code

```
const btn = document.getElementById("btn-1");

function addPara() {
  console.log("adding para");
  const para = document.createElement('p');
  const randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
  para.textContent="MOKASMOCHA " + randomNum;
  console.log("adding text ");
  document.body.appendChild(para);
}

// btn.onClick = addPara;
btn.addEventListener("click",addPara);
```

Goal: Everytime you click the button a new paragraph element will be added to the body.

first tried using btn.onClick but do not know what was going wrong here.
Tried addEventListener and everything seems to work.

Comment: your codepen link contains an empty editor (in case it's supposed to contain anything more than the JS you put in the question)

Comment: Rather than using codepen, use the `<>` icon and add a demo here in SO.

Comment: It's `onclick` not `onClick`

Comment: Have a look and read up on MDN about click events => https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event

Answer (score 1):

There's a slight error of syntax, that's why, the correct event is [`onclick`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) without any uppercase.

I would recommend the `addEventListener` method though, you can't mess it up and it clearly shows what it does.